# angular will not work ng serve npm install

Tags: angular, npm

When I run ng serve, I get

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
See "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-7WixLR\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

When I run npm install, I get

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.1.0-rc.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^10.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1002.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^10.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1002.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-27T04_53_05_050Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-27T04_53_05_050Z-debug-0.log
```

I did `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps` before ng serve.

I tried everything and nothing has worked.  I can't even create a simple angular app.
I'm using VS code and Windows 10.
node version 18.14.2
npm version 9.6.2

When I run `npx ng version` I get

```
Unknown error: Error: Cannot find module 'is-fullwidth-code-point'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\string-width\index.js
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\yargs\node_modules\cliui\build\index.cjs
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\yargs\build\index.cjs
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\yargs\index.cjs
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-module.js
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\user1\Documents\learning-angular\first-app-lesson-00\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
```

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the node version? I did encounter similar issue before, solved it by downgrading the node environment to 14. There is a handy tool called `nvm` lets you quickly install and switch between multiple node environments